# Get user with same package id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 3 tables one is **user** second is **user_packages** and the last one is **packages**. **user** table contains some information like name, email etc and **user_packages** table contains **userID** as a foreign key **packageID** and **status** of each package. Only one package can be activated at one time. **packages** table contains all the packages. Now i want to get the record in such a way that if I log in to the system I can see only one user which does not have matching id of the current session open. After getting that information the result will be stored in donor table. In this way there will be a relationship between users who will pay whom. I have the following query which is working very fine getting record of other person.

```
$this -> db -> query("Select * from user JOIN user_packages ON 
user.id!='$id' AND user.canRecieve!='1' AND user.active='1' AND
user.id=user_packages.userID AND user_packages.status='1' ORDER BY RAND(),
user.id LIMIT 1");
```

Now what my main concern is that only those users should be visible to me which also has same **packgeID** as of the current user including above conditions. Let say I have packageID of 5 I want to select the person/user which also belongs to that packageID of 5.

[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psv7d.png)

[User Packages Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw8i7.png)

Comment: join `packages` table in query with packgeID

Comment: can you design the query?

Answer (score 1):

So here is the answer after tried of many queries finally got the query which gives the correct output

```
$this -> db -> query("Select user.id, user.name, user.canRecieve,
user.active from (Select user.id, canRecieve, status, packageID, active from
user JOIN user_packages ON user.id='$id' AND user.canRecieve!='1' AND
user.active='1' AND user_packages.userID=user.id AND user_packages.status='1')
AS DONOR JOIN user ON user.id!='$id' AND user.canRecieve!='1' AND
user.active='1' JOIN user_packages ON user.id=user_packages.userID AND
user_packages.status='1' AND user_packages.packageID=DONOR.packageID ORDER BY
RAND(), DONOR.id LIMIT 1");
```